# Display hexagon grid to visualize Langton's ant

Tags: graphics, geometry, visualization, grid-layouts

I am looking to recreate the following image from [this reference](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#coordinates) as
[image: Hexagon Grid]

using [Mathematica's Polygon documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html) under "Applications" as a starting point. I want to eventually use Mathematica to visualize the evolution of multi-colored Langton's ant on a hexagonal grid (not too important). In working to create the `z = 0` row (shown in the above image as blue 0's) using `Polygon` and `Graphics`. I generate a hexagon using Mathematica's example with a `Pi/6` rotation as follows:

```
rotatePoint[c_, p_, θ_] := {
     (p[[1]] - c[[1]]) Cos[θ] - (p[[2]] - c[[2]]) Sin[θ] + c[[1]], 
     (p[[1]] - c[[1]]) Sin[θ] + (p[[2]] - c[[2]]) Cos[θ] + c[[2]]
  }
hexagonPoly[x_, y_] := 
 Polygon[
   Table[rotatePoint[{x, y}, {Cos[2 Pi k/6] + x, Sin[2 Pi k/6] + y}, Pi/6], 
   {k, 6}]]
```

to create a polygon at the center of `{x, y}` with side-length 1 rotated appropriately. I then look to create a row of these polygons evenly spaced so that their sides are touching as in the above image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b14Z.png). For this I am thinking that each center will be `2r` away from the adjacent centers' where `r` is defined as the length from the center point to the center of the side and is `Sqrt[3]/2 * t` where `t` is the side length as [defined from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon#Parameters). Therefore, I am trying to create hexagons where ith hexagon is `Sqrt[3] * i` away from `{0,0}`. To accomplish this I have the following code

```
hexgrid[xrange_, yrange_] := 
 Table[hexagonPoly[x + x*Sqrt[3], 0], {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Opacity[1]], LightRed, hexgrid[{0, 2}, {0, 0}]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

which produces the following output

[image: My Output]

I think that my maths are "solid" here in how I want to layout the polygons but I cannot seem to get them in the right configuration. How can I get my hexagons to touch at the edges in a row as such where I create a polygon based on where the center point should be (which I'd calculate based on the side-length of each hexagon)?

Thank you in advance! I am not proficient in Mathematica so I believe my error to be how I'm programming but it could be that I've missed something obvious in the problem and my code is correct :)

Comment: It's simpler to use `CirclePoints` than make the points up yourself: `With[{rm = RotationMatrix[30 Degree]},
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Red], 
   Polygon[rm.# & /@ CirclePoints[6]]}]
 ]`

Comment: Awesome - thank you for that because it definitely makes it cleaner. This basically applies the rotation matrix to these `CirclePoints[6]` then creates a Polygon object from that?

Comment: @flinty You can have it even easier with `Polygon[CirclePoints[{1, Pi/6}, 6]]`...

Answer (score 13):

Oh, what a fun topic to play with. Thank you for showing it to me.

If you are interested, here is a simple implementation of the colored Langton Ant that does not generate a grid in the beginning but just stores the center coordinate of each visited tile along with its current color in an `Association`, a flexibly extendable data structure with decently efficient lookup (basically a hash table).

This is the way to set it up: `k` is the number of edges of the tile shape (use `k = 4` for quads and `k = 6` for hexagons; anything else won't work). `R` and `L` are the corresponding rotations and `rule` is a simple list of `R`s and `L`s defining the turning rules.

```
k = 6;
R = RotationMatrix[-2 Pi/k];
L = RotationMatrix[2 Pi/k];

rule = {L, L, R, R};
shape[x_] := Polygon[CirclePoints[x, {1, Pi/k}, k]];
x = {0, 0};
v = 2 Mean[shape[{0, 0}][[1, 1 ;; 2]]];
fields = Association[];
nstates = Length[rule];
colors = Prepend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length[rule] - 1], White];

step[] := With[{state = Mod[Lookup[fields, Key[x], 1] + 1, nstates, 1]},
   AssociateTo[fields, x -> state];
   v = rule[[state]].v;
   x = x + v;
   ];
```

This is how you can simulate `10000` steps:

```
Do[step[], {10000}];
```

And this is how to visualize the final state:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thin],
  Transpose[{
    colors[[Values[fields]]],
    Map[shape, Keys[fields]]
    }]
  }]
```

[image]

And here the result of 200000 steps for `k = 6; rule = {L, R, R, L};`:

[image]

## Remark

This relies on *Mathematica* fully simplyfing the entries of `x`, so that the `Lookup`s into `field` work out correctly. Actually not super efficient, inparticular, as this involves some costly exact arithmethic. However, using floating point numbers instead would not work because `Lookup` does not tolerate rounding errors.

Comment: Thank you! Wow what a complete answer!! I am planning to have my students in a C++ programming class implement Langton's ant and then I'll provide them with some visualization. However, I do like to expose them to other programming languages and styles and will definitely show this to them. I'll have to play around with this code to understand fully because I've not used Mathematica extensively.

Comment: That's great to hear! You're welcome! Well, using the center coordinate of a cell as key probably won't work in C++ hash tables (because hashing with floating point numbers does not work well), but you can index each cell by a pair of integers instead... (That will require changing almost everything of that implementation, though =/)

Answer (score 11):

Here's a quick way to create a hex grid by exploiting [`ResourceFunction["HextileBins"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HextileBins) so you don't need to think too hard about placement:

```
centers = With[{d = 3}, 
  Select[{({{1, 1/2}, {0, Sqrt[3]/2}}.#), #} & /@ 
     Tuples[Range[-d, d], {2}], Norm[First[#]] <= d &]];

tiles = Keys[ResourceFunction["HextileBins"][centers[[All, 1]], 1]];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], 
  Riffle[FaceForm /@ Lighter[RandomColor[Length@tiles]], tiles], 
  Black, Text[ToString@Last@#1, First[#1]] & /@ centers}]
```

[image: hex grid]

Let me know if that's helpful enough to get you started on adding the remaining details to the diagram.

Comment: @Anton Antonov thanks for contributing HextileBins to the function repository. It's really useful.

Comment: Thanks for using it here! BTW, I made `HextileBins` in order to do better [geo-spatial-temporal COVID-19 simulations](https://github.com/antononcube/SystemModeling/blob/master/Projects/Coronavirus-propagation-dynamics/Documents/Epidemiology-Compartmental-Modeling-Monad-Demo.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

```
n = 3;
Graphics[Table[If[Abs[i + j] <= n, With[{c = {i + j/2, √3 j/2}},
    {Text[{i, j}, c], EdgeForm[Gray], RGBColor[Abs@{i/n, j/n, 1, 0.5}], 
     RegularPolygon[c, {1/√3, Pi/2}, 6]}]], {i, -n, n}, {j, -n, n}]
]
```

[image]
Another way, labeling coordinate may not be convenient

```
n = 10;
Graphics[Table[{ColorData["Pastel", i/(n+1)],
    Polygon@ReIm@Table[√3.5 (-1)^(j/3) (((-1)^(1/3) - 1) k + i) + I (-1)^(l/3), {l, 6}]},
   {i, n}, {j, 6}, {k, i}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: i think in terms of the visualization this solves my problem completely. So N defines the "wings", i.e., the number of hexagons on either end of the middle hexagon in the middle row? Then I assume that changing the color data requires a list of ColorData where each element corresponds to the index of that polygon??

Comment: +1 for `RegularPolygon`. I did not know it before.

Comment: @C.Fuhrman You are right.